# Extensionless URLs not working

Tags: php, asp.net, iis-8

I have a PHP site in IIS 8.5 and within that site I have an ASP.NET 4.0 application.  The pages in the application are working as long as I put the extension on the end, but are not working when the RoutingTable removes the extensions.

The Handler Mapping is there for the Extensionless URLs, but I don't see anything else that I'm missing.  What other settings are needed?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure. This is for the ASP.NET application.  It's working fine for the PHP site.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.

Comment: Did anyone have this working? I'm having the same issue.